# In inheritance, does every child component cause the parent to re-import assets?

Tags: angular, typescript

**Parent Component**

```
import xyzJson from 'assets/xyz.json'
// other imports
```

From my understanding, this will directly bundle `xyz.json` in the minified javascript of `ParentComponent`.

Now, if 10 other components extend from `ParentComponent` like `export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent`, will `xyzJson` be reimported for each child component?

I'm just trying to guage how many extra kilobytes this will cause my application to load.

Comment: It's not actually related to inheritance, and quite vaguely related to angular.
The actual  bundles are generated by webpack, which is smart enough to extract reused files into a separate chunk. This is, of course, if we're talking about a regular angular app and not smth crazy like manually creating a separate bundle for each component

Comment: The answer is yes. Each child is-a Parent component and more.